# Different header wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to use **a different header** on some pages of my Wordpress website. 
I'm using the code below to do this. I do

```
<?php get_header( $name ) ?>
```

I have two header-files in my directory: **header.php** and **header-frontpage.php**
Below you can also see a picture of my Wordpress directory (just to give the best information)

[image: Wordpress directory]

The **"main-template" of my page** is build up in **page.php**. (you can find get_header(), get_footer(), ... there). I changed the **get_header() part** code into:

```
if(is_front_page())
{
    get_header();
}
else 
{
    get_header( 'others' );
}
```

This is working for me but **only on the pages, not on post pages.** I can do the same thing on the **main-template for the post pages** but is this correct? Can somebody assist me or am I doing 
everything correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do almost the same as you except for one thing. I would reverse the headers like this:

```
if(is_front_page())
{
    get_header('frontpage');
}
else 
{
    get_header();
}
```